# Android studio gradle build make whole computer slow

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When using gradle build in android studio whole computer become slow.I cant even open browser.Typing text during gradle build is also very slow.Is this a common problem .Any way to solve this?

Comment: it is common problem. you need to Upgrade you pc to faster run.

Comment: what are your pc specs? AS will use 100% of the CPU and sometimes 100% of disk speed for short periods of times when you build projects or performing background tasks. You need a good PC preferably a desktop and preferably a Solid State Disks to speed up AS operations. Otherwise the norm is to wait until AS has finished its operations especially Gradle time build etc, and not try to open browsers or watch dvd's etc. There be better versions of AS in he future so keep an eye of updates because there are bugs and performance issues within every application too.

Comment: @Tasos I am using a desktop.My have processor is intell i3.Ram is 4GB. One problem with it is the ram is 2 ram of 2GB each.But each of them have different speed.Does that can be a problem?

Comment: memory modules should be the same  speed. even if one is faster than the other as far as i know the faster one will match the slower memory speed.  the speeds are capped to the slower one. so never mix them its not recommended , there's no gain and can decrease performance.

Comment: Now I updated all to marshmallow its look like problem solved.The gradle build is very fast and its max take 30s.

Comment: Mine is Core i5, 8GB RAM, HDD, even opening websites are a problem while gradle is running. This is pathetic.

Comment: i7, SSD, 16fastRam and still slow. Will update if I handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to limit the CPU speed Gradle/Android Studio is allowed to allocate.

Windows:
https://superuser.com/questions/214566/are-there-solutions-that-can-limit-the-cpu-usage-of-a-process

Linux:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/469709/gradle-compiling-slows-down-my-computer

As mentioned in a comment above, the root of your problem could be a different device like your harddisk.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar issue when Gradle was not able to solve certain dependencies. Check out that Gradle is not hanged while trying to retrieve something.